# How to show results with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problem with AJAX and database. I don't know what I have now to do.
So, I have this AJAX code:

```
<script>
function showCity(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","rozpiski.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

I want: 
When user select some option, the second select list shows value (after gets this values from database).

This is my code HTML:

```
<select name="country3" onchange="showCity(this.value)"> <option>Anglia</option><option selected='selected'>Austria</option><option>Belgia</option><option>Czechy</option><option>Dania</option><option>Estonia</option><option>Finlandia</option><option>Francja</option><option>Holandia</option><option>Islandia</option><option>Lichtenstein</option><option>Luxembourg</option><option>Niemcy</option><option>Norwegia</option><option>Polska</option><option>Szwajcaria</option><option>Szwecja</option><option>Słowacja</option><option>Słowenia</option><option>Wyspy Owcze</option><option>Węgry</option><option>Włochy</option><option>Łotwa</option><option>Anglia</option><option>Austria</option><option>Belgia</option><option>Czechy</option><option>Dania</option><option>Estonia</option><option>Finlandia</option><option>Francja</option><option>Holandia</option><option>Islandia</option><option>Lichtenstein</option><option>Luxembourg</option><option>Niemcy</option><option>Norwegia</option><option>Polska</option><option>Szwajcaria</option><option>Szwecja</option><option>Słowacja</option><option>Słowenia</option><option selected='selected'>Wyspy Owcze</option><option>Węgry</option><option>Włochy</option><option>Łotwa</option><option>Anglia</option><option>Austria</option><option>Belgia</option><option>Czechy</option><option>Dania</option><option>Estonia</option><option>Finlandia</option><option>Francja</option><option>Holandia</option><option>Islandia</option><option>Lichtenstein</option><option>Luxembourg</option><option>Niemcy</option><option>Norwegia</option><option>Polska</option><option>Szwajcaria</option><option>Szwecja</option><option>Słowacja</option><option>Słowenia</option><option>Wyspy Owcze</option><option>Węgry</option><option>Włochy</option><option>Łotwa</option></select></td>
                                 <td><select name="city" id="3"></select>
```

When the user in country3 select for example Polska, he gets in 2nd select cities from Polska. This cities are in database. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your html select-option tags should be:

```
<select name="country3" onchange="showCity(this.value)">
    <option value="city">City</option>
</select>
```